# How to share tabular data in txt form from Databricks via Outlook?

Tags: database, azure, outlook, databricks, azure-data-share

I want to send the file in a simple txt format (and not as a .dbx file) which makes me wonder if any type of coding/automation done on this. Select or copy, paste is a way but not scalable and efficient.

I have explored different ways which involve sending a .dbx file and converting it in PST over Outlook 365 but I want to know if there are any alternatives.

Comment: Just to make sure, do you want to send the notebook itself? Or some data that you are working on?

Comment: Want to send the data I am working on. i.e. daily/monthly records or values, some kind of string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data attached to an email in Databricks:

Step 1:

Save the data from your dataframe to a file (csv,txt).

```
#create a manual dataframe with some data
from pyspark.sql import Row
df = sc.parallelize([ \
    Row(first_name='Alice', last_name='whatever'), \
    Row(first_name='Jenny', last_name='whatever'), \
    Row(first_name='Bob', last_name='whatever')]).toDF()
#save that dataframe to a csv file
df.write.option("delimiter", ",").option("header", True).csv("/mnt/filepath/filename.csv")
```

You can also save to a txt file with:

```
df.write.text("/mnt/filepath/filename.txt")
```

But these method only supports one column.

Step 2:
Add some library or connect to external service that send emails, and attach the file created in the first step.

Here is and example using SendGrid service:

https://databitsdigital.wordpress.com/2020/10/14/sending-e-mail-notifications-directly-from-azure-databricks-using-sendgrid/